# Authenticated app on appengine with angularjs

Tags: google-app-engine, angularjs

Setup:

- templates: angularjs (all statically served from app.yaml)
- api: json responses used by angularjs controllers to pull data from application

The page content is served from a static file so it is not possible to use [users.create_login_url()](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/functions#create_login_url), [users.create_logout_url()](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/functions#create_logout_url), etc.

How do you typically go about users logging in/out, figuring if user is logged in/out, user is admin on an application like this?

Answer (score 7):

I'm actually working on a solution to this problem myself. The project is called [Sapling](http://github.com/scotch/sapling) -- it's an AngularJS starter project that covers User management.

This is the approach that I took:

1. User comes to the site  -- load html and javascript
2. After Angular is loaded make a `GET` request to `'/api/user/me'`.
   If the user is logged in return a representation of the user, E.g.

   ```
   { 
     "name": "Bob",
     "admin": false,
     // ect.
   }
   ```

   If the user is ***not*** logged in return a `401` error.
3. If a user object is returned -- check to see if the user is also and admin. If a `401` is received redirect the user to the login pages (You could create a login page within your Angular app, or if you feel the user will not get confused you could send them to the Google login directly).

#### So, how do you do this with App Engine's User Service?

In your request handler for the url **'/api/user/me'**

Call `get_current_user()` and `is_current_user_admin()`

- User is logged in -- append the admin `boolean` and return the representation of the user as json.
- User is not logged in -- return a `401` Unauthorized, i.e. `response.set_status(401)`

#### How do you direct the user to the login and logout urls?

You can create request handlers at the following urls:

**'api/user/login'**

```
webapp2.redirect(users.create_login_url())
```

**'api/user/logout'**

```
webapp2.redirect(users.create_logout_url())
```

And direct users to them from Angular.

I think that I covered the basics. If you need more details, please let me know.

Comment: This sounds like what I have right now but it is not robust enough. If authentication credentials become stale, operations (api calls) will start failing and the user needs to re-login. When this happens you will need to somehow show a login window, login and then restart the operations.

I have found [this](http://www.espeo.pl/2012/02/26/authentication-in-angularjs-application) which talks about an $http interceptor that on first look I believe does what I want.

Comment: Yes it is but it is still not clear if this will work with Google Accounts authentication (not OAuth2). It seems that this part is unsolved.

Comment: @user1395626 if I understand correctly you're asking how to maintain the "state" of the application during loggin? I would suggest opening a popup window with js. Here's how I [authenticated using App Engine openid with Sapling](http://sapling.scotchmedia.com/login). The backend is written in Go, but the principals are the same. [sapling-aego](https://github.com/scotch/sapling-aego)

Comment: @user1395626 And just to clarify. In the last step I'm suggesting that you create handlers for login and logout that redirect the user to the Google Accounts Authentication login. In this way it doesn't mater if you are using Google Accounts or OAuth / OpenID.

Comment: How does this relate to OAuth/OpenID? If I would like to use the REST API from an Android client, how would the authentication flow look?

Comment: @joscarsson, I'm not sure. I haven't used AngularJS on an Android client, but I think it would work the same way. What problems are you having? Could you create a new question?

Comment: Thanks for answering. I am not talking about AngularJS on Android, I'm talking about authenticating an Android app which wants to use the same REST API AngularJS uses. I'll start a separate question about it when I get there if I can't sort it out :)

Answer (score -2):

See also this question: [Limiting access to a static file with GAE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692798/limiting-access-to-a-static-file-with-gae)
when serving static content.

In your handler you can use the user service to find out who logged and if this "user" is an administrator.
An example: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/overview

OAUTH2 is a better option if you use a client application.

Comment: The static content should be visible to all. The problem is when the client javascript requests something through the REST api on appengine it might not be authenticated. Somehow this needs to be intercepted, login window shown to the user and then retry the REST api call.

Comment: The static content is visible to all, if your app.yaml for static does not contain a login: required or admin. For script login, you have to use OAUTH2. Try this link : https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile&state=%2Fprofile&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Foauth2-login-demo.appspot.com%2Foauthcallback&response_type=token&client_id=812741506391.apps.googleusercontent.com

Comment: The example OAUTH2 link is taken from: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login  By the way: the old client login is depricated.